# Problema ao lista diretórios com java

Tags: java, lista, recursão, diretório, io

Estou tentando listar todos os arquivos do diretório C:\ do meu PC. Diretórios menores com 11 mil arquivos está pegando normalmente, demora um pouco, mas é nenhum problema. O problema é quando vou listar os arquivos do C:\, por ser a pasta raiz e ter pelo menos 1 milhão arquivos e de meu método está usando recursividade ele dar NullPointer. Existe alguma maneira de listar o C: por completo de um jeito prático?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class PercorrendoArquivosComSubPasta {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<File> list = (ArrayList<File>) buscaRecursiva(new File("C:\\Users\\Joel\\Desktop\\"),".txt");
        for(File i : list) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

    public static List<File> buscaRecursiva(File dir, String extensao) {

        List<File> listFile = new ArrayList<File>();

        for (File f : dir.listFiles()){
           if (f.isDirectory()) {
               listFile.addAll(buscaRecursiva(f, extensao));

           } else if (f.getName().endsWith(extensao)) {
               listFile.add(f);
           } 
        }
        return listFile;
    }

}
```

[CODIGO NO PASTEBIN](https://pastebin.com/b4qHjkHv)

Comment: Leia aqui: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/28595

Comment: O codigo deve ser colado aqui e nao em link externo, de preferencia.

Comment: Certo, próximo post passarei a colocar. Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentação do método `File.listFiles()`:

> Returns null if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or
>   if an I/O error occurs.

ou seja, retorna `null` se o caminho não representa um diretório. O que é esperado que aconteça no caso de todos os arquivos que não são diretórios.

**EDIT:** Fiz um teste aqui no Linux e deu `NullPointerException` ao tentar ler uma pasta que eu não tinha permissão para ler. Para fazer essa checagem no código basta usar `file.canRead()`. Exemplo:

```
import java.io.File;

public class ListFiles {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        if (args.length > 0) {
            File file = new File(args[0]);
            listar(file);
        }
    }

    private static void listar(File file) {
        System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
        if (file.isDirectory() && file.canRead()) {
            File[] files = file.listFiles();
            for (File f : files) {
                listar(f);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Piovezan, existe alguma método para percorrer todo o diretório junto com suas sub-pastas?

Comment: Não sugeri questão por não ter feito nenhum teste com o código. Mas ele está quase correto, acho que é questão de checar por `null` antes de usar um objeto ou então testar `arquivo.isDirectory()` antes de chamar`arquivo.listFiles()`.

Comment: Também evitaria declarar `listFile` dentro de `buscaRecursiva()`, declararia fora e passaria como parâmetro para esse método.

Comment: Sugiro olhar [esta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056221/recursively-list-files-in-java) (em inglês) mostrando diversas alternativas para listar arquivos recursivamente em Java.

Comment: Obrigado Piovezan, Irei dar uma olhada.

Comment: Só lembrando que além de aceitar uma resposta você também pode votar +1 nela. Aliás pode votar +1 em qualquer resposta que achar útil e correta.

Comment: Só é permitido quando tem 15 ou mais reputações.